# How to make 3.42m x 1.75m size pdf file with 300 dpi?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, pdf

I'm working to make big size pdf file for printing.
3.42m x 1.75m (300 dpi)
Printing company need 300dpi file.
I tried it in Indesign and Photoshop, but failed.
Please help me.
Regards.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and include what exactly have you tried? Have you searched for a tutorial for either software?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by failed? You should also check that the company really does require a 300dpi file as it is more common to print large formats at lower resolution (or scale - i.e 1.71m x 0.875m @ 150dpi)

Answer (score 1):

This category can range wildly from advertising posters, vehicle wraps, 2 story billboards, etc. The variable to consider is the distance the viewer will be from the material. A person driving on a highway will never be able to discern the difference between 300dpi on a billboard and 40dpi. You would up close, of course, but the only people viewing a billboard up close are those installing it. Most advertising posters can get away with 100ppi. Vehicle wraps, much less.
The vendor may ask you to provide art at a smaller size than the actual printed size. For instance, if a billboard is to be 20' wide, the vendor may ask you to send a file 20 inches wide. If the billboard will be printed at 40ppi, then your 20" wide file would need to be set to 480ppi to allow for the scaling (12X40). Hope this helps.

Comment: While true, I don't think this answer relates to the question.

Comment: Totally relates to the question. A 300 ppi file of 3mts has no sense. The "print" company has no idea on what they are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I created a file with those dimensions and dpi, Photoshop issued a warning that images larger than 30000 pixels in any would not be backward compatible. When I wanted to save this file, I had to save it in PSB format reserved for files larger than 2GB. Also noteworthy was the missing PDF format among the option. Based on this, I will conclude that these parameters will result in a file that cannot be saved as a PDF file.

Your options seem to be:

1. Discuss the matter with the printer and ask if lower dpi could work
2. Ask if you could deliver the file in PSB format, if they have Photoshop they should be able to open and print from it
3. If the project allows, print smaller segments to assemble after the printing is done
4. Print smaller size